# 2 divs both 100% next to each other

Tags: css, html, css-float

Quite simple question but tried about everything.

what i want is 2 (actually 5) divs next to eachother with the class "container" so i can make a horizontal 1page website. Each div has to be 100% wide. so 2 divs mean 2 screens next to eachother.

This is the css line i have now:

```
.container { width: 100%; float: left; display: inline; }
```

I cant get them to line up next to each other.

Here is a visual to make it more clear.
[image]
image url for bigger preview: http://www.luukratief.com/stackoverflow.png

The scrolling part is not the issue for me, just the placement of the divs.

Is this possible using percentages or is this simply not possible.
If so, please tell me how to do this with css.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: by 100% wide, do you mean each div has equal width (1/5th of the window), or they all take up the entire width of the window (the page is 5 windows wide)?

Comment: @hughes Each div equals 1 entire width of the window. It has to be this way (cannot use px) due to different screen resolutions.

Comment: If you're going to use such a method, why not make it vertical instead of horizontal? This would be easy to do vertically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a container with 200% width and then put two divs inside of that element with 50% width so you will make sure that one div always gets the whole visitors screen width.

For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="contentContainer"></div>
    <div class="contentContainer"></div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 200%;
}

.contentContainer {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: you sir are awesome! logical answer... now why didnt i come up with that?? thanks heaps!

Comment: You just ended a 30 hour lookup ... thanks sir! - also do you think the `auto` between the 2 different containers would work ?

Answer (score 4):

How does this look to you?

http://jsfiddle.net/2wrzn/19/

Note that the border isn't required. I was using it for testing. Turning it on also makes one of the divs wrap around, so it's turned off.

Answer (score 3):

you should use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float` anf then wrap all five divs in another container or use the body element and add `white-space: nowrap` to it.

If the design is incredibly pixel perfect, you can remove the actual "word-spacing"  between the inline-blocks by removing the whitespace in the HTML or by giving them a negative right margin of about 0.25em; but if scrolling to new "page" you dn't notice it anyway..

#### [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/clairesuzy/n9dGd/)

HTML Code:

```
<div class="container" id="p1">Page 1 => <a href="#p2">Next page</a></div>
<div class="container" id="p2">Page 2 => <a href="#p3">Next page</a></div>
<div class="container" id="p3">Page 3 => <a href="#p4">Next page</a></div>
<div class="container" id="p4">Page 4 => <a href="#p5">Next page</a></div>
<div class="container" id="p5">Page 5 => <a href="#p1">Next page</a></div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}

body {white-space: nowrap;}

.container {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.container {
   display: inline !ie7; /* for working inline-blocks in IE7 and below */
}

.container * {white-space: normal;}

#p1 {background: #fcf;}
#p2 {background: #ff0;}
#p3 {background: #cfc;}
#p4 {background: #abc;}
#p5 {background: #cba;}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them next to each other then they can't be 100%.  width: 100% will force the div to take up the full width of it's containing element, in this case the full width of the window I guess.

If you want two screens next to each other you'd need to set the width of each to 50%.  If I've misunderstood you're question add a bit more detail.

Comment: well basically what i want is a 1page (horizontal) website with 5 different slides. I can make a dirty solution (give the divs a 3000px width with a left:-50%), but that is not really what i am looking for. I want to use percentage to solve the problem of different screen resolutions.

I dont know if i can explain it better then this....

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, but you may have compatibility problems with IE and table* (but you can consider http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ to fix that)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html { width: 500%; display: table; }
body { width: 100%; display: table-row; overflow-x: scroll}
.container { width: 20%; display: table-cell; }
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">Test1</div>
<div class="container">Test2</div>
<div class="container">Test3</div>
<div class="container">Test4</div>
<div class="container">Test5</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure IE7.js doesn't implement `display: table*`.

Comment: you're right -- i should have known, as I've documented a workaround to that: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/issues/detail?id=259#c6

Comment: Haha, yeah in that case, you really should have known :) I wish it *did* support it.

Answer (score 0):

The % width of the divs is a percentage of the width of the tags they are contained in and ultimately the body tag (i.e. not the window). So the body tag must be 100 * n where n is the number of div tags you want side-by-side. The example below has 2 div tags thus the body is 200% (2 * 100). Each the div tag's; width is a percentage of the body tag's width roughly 100 / n (need a smidgen less). Don't forget to factor in margin and padding. Here's an example:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body{
     width:200%;
     margin:0%;
     padding:0%;
    }

    #dvScreen1, #dvScreen2{
     width:49.95%;
     height:80%;
     clear:none;

    }
    #dvScreen1 {
    float:left;
    border:solid black 1px
   }

   #dvScreen2{
    float:right;
    border:solid blue 1px
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id="dvScreen1">
   <p>Screen 1 stuff ...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="dvScreen2">
   <p>Screen 2 stuff ...</p>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```