# divs of 100% width next to one another

Tags: css, html, markup

I have up to 4 divs on the page that will have to 'sit next to' each other horizontally. Each div will have 100% width.

All, but the first one, will therefore appear off the page until I style it otherwise (ultimately using jQuery).

How can I style the divs in order to achieve this?

**Markup:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="panel">
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
    </div>
</div>
```

**What I've Tried**

I've tried floating all of the divs left and setting the overflow of 'wrapper' to hidden. I've tried setting the display to inline-block of all the divs. I've tried position absolute on all the divs. I'm trying a combination of different things just hoping it'll work but there has to be a proper approach to this.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6597889/2-divs-both-100-next-to-each-other?rq=1

Comment: Heres a fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/chriz123/3CpL8/3/

Answer (score 1):

Tell me if some like this is what you want i use `display:inline-block`

**http://jsfiddle.net/fdXLb/**

Then i can do a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

if one div has a width of 100% there will be no space for another div to align next to this one.

so I would say to align them use only 20% width.

25% works also for 4 divs but then you can not use any borders, margin or padding.

also you can set a min-width in px.

have a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/3CpL8/
may it helps

```
.wrapper > div {
    width:20%;
    background-color:orange;
    height:60px;
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but I need each div to fill the screen width-wise or for it to at least appear as though it does.

Comment: @deemac well then 25% and inside go for 100% http://jsfiddle.net/3CpL8/1/ does that the job?

Answer (score 0):

A nice trick is to use `white-space: nowrap;` to prevent divs moving to the next line. This is what your css would look like:

```
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrapper > div {
  width:100%;
  background-color:red;
  height:60px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width:100px;
  margin:5px;
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CpL8/2/) and use your browser's inspector it to see that the divs are still there, but off screen at the width you want. I assumed you'd want to continue using `overflow-x: hidden;` on the parent div so there wouldn't be an ugly scrollbar when doing the javascript side :)